# firefox opens aspx page for download

Tags: asp.net, firefox, download

I am trying to load an aspx page in an iframe. the problem is that the iframe loads correctly in ie but in firefox and chrome, they open the aspx file for download and it starts to download the aspx page instead of rendering it in the iframe. when I download the aspx page, there are some sort of code at the top of the page, which I do not know where they are coming from. the code is as follows

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="text/plain";
    boundary="-=MicrosoftCrm.HTTP.MultipartResponse.Boundary"

This is a multi-part message In MIME format.


---=MicrosoftCrm.HTTP.MultipartResponse.Boundary
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset="utf-8'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=EF=BB=BF<html> ......</html>
```

I use a multi part response to send the html to the browser. When I do not et anthing for set the multipart response content type, it download the page. When I set the content type to text/html, it does not download the file anymore but it shows all of the aspx page code in the iframe.

What is going wrong?

Comment: is working in any other browser? or if you directly open that aspx page in browser?

Comment: As I said it works in internet explorer correctly and If I directly open the page in firefox. it downloads the page

Comment: can you provide the iframe code you have used?

Comment: see this link- that might help you -http://forums.asp.net/t/1733169.aspx?Firefox+7+0+1+wants+to+download+aspx+files

Comment: I have read that post. I have read more than 100 posts on this issue but none of them has solved my problem.